# How to handle legacy OCX files in a Visual Basic Project

Tags: vb6, ocx

I have inherited an old VBP project that is ostensibly usable in Visual Basic 6.

It has two .ocx files which, research seems to indicate, need to be registered with regsvr32. Loading VB6 onto a Windows XP installation seems to allow me to successfully register them both.

However, VB6 still chokes on them. When I load the project, two errors are logged:

```
Line 228: Class CvsInSightDisplayOcx.CvsInSightDisplay of control Camera1 was not a loaded control class.
Line 5841: Class Xtimer01.Xtimer of control Xtimer1 was not a loaded control class.
```

And, naturally, the project will not compile. What steps can I take to get these .ocx files to play well?

Comment: 3rd party libraries often require developer licenses and may have subdependencies.  You'd need to get the original installers from the supplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bob77's comment led me to a two part resolution.

1) One of the components needed to be formally installed. (Thankfully it was still available.)
2) Both needed to be manually removed from the .vdp file using Notepad, and added via the VB6 UI, through Project -> Components... and 'Browse...'